# How do I handle Thread Errors in Tweepy

Tags: python, multithreading, tweepy

I am writing a program which uses Tweepy to get data from Twitter. Tweepy uses another thread, and on occasion this thread throws an exception. However, my error catching logic does not catch the exceptions because they occur in a different thread. Is there any way to catch exceptions that are thrown by other threads without changing the thread's code?

To clarify, I needed to use the extra thread option in Tweepy so that the stream wouldn't block the rest of my program from executing. I get occasional updates from a database regarding which Twitter accounts to track, and the only way I was able to do this while streaming was to stream on a separate thread.

```
while 1:
    # Create twitter stream 
    try:
        # Reconnect to the stream if it was disconnected (or at start)
        if reconnect:
            reconnect = False

            # NEW THREAD CREATED HERE
            tweet_stream.filter(follow=twitter_uids, async=True)

        # Sleep for sleep_interval before checking for new usernames
        time.sleep(sleep_interval)
        users_update = get_user_names(twitter_usernames)

        # Restart the stream if new users were found in DB
        if len(users_update) != 0:

            # Disconnect and set flag for stream to be restarted with new usernames
            twitter_usernames = users_update
            twitter_uids = get_twitter_uids(users_update)
            reconnect = True

            tweet_stream.disconnect()
            tweet_stream._thread.join()

    except Exception as e:
        # ERROR HANDLING CODE
```

Comment: Isn't the extra thread optional?  Can you show us your code?

Comment: Did you try to set async to False or overload Stream.filter?